# How to insert data into 2 tables with relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2013

Let assume we have

`ID int32` , `FirstNam text`, `LastName text` (`Table 1`)

`ID int32` , `book text` (`Table 2`)

and i have a relation ship between `Table1 ID` Parent and `Table2 ID` is the child
how i can write query to insert multiple data in `table 2` base on one data in `table 1`.

Comment: So which database is it? MySQL, SQL Server or Access?

Comment: Do you want to insert all the IDs that you have in Table 1 into Table 2?

Comment: i want my data base to be access its like  i have student want to borrow a book and he can chose multiple books based on ID

Comment: I added my approach to the problem you have, but as dotnetom asked, which database are u using? MySQL, Postgresql, Sqlite, access, SQL Server, Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a third table doing the relation many to many.

```
IDUser int, FirstName text, LastName text (Table 1)
IDBook int, Book text (Table 2)
IDBook int, IDUser int (Table 3)
```

When an user borrow a book you need to add a record in the Table 3.

Ex.
You have:

```
Table 1:
User 1 (IDUser: 1), User 2 (IDUser: 2), User 3 (IDUser: 3)

Table 2: 
Book 1 (IDBook: 1), Book 2 (IDBook: 2), Book 3 (IDBook: 3), Book 4 (IDBook: 4)
```

Let suppose that User 2 borrows Book 1 and 3. You will have:

```
Table 3:
IDUser 2, IDBook 1
IDUser 2, IDBook 3
```

To Insert Data to Table 3 you can do with

User 2 - Book 1

```
INSERT INTO Table3(IDUser, IDBook)
VALUES(2, 1)
```

User 2 - Book 3

```
INSERT INTO Table3(IDUser, IDBook)
VALUES(2, 3)
```

To query all the books borrowed by User 2 the query will be:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table1
  JOIN Table3 ON Table1.IDUser = Table3.IDUser
  JOIN Table2 ON Table2.IDBook = Table3.IDBook
WHERE
  Table1.IDUser = 2
```

Hope This helps

Comment: Hello here is the data base i just want to query from table 1 and i dont know how plz help me i dont know why i need table 3 
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AC25D7A2DC192BDB!13075&authkey=!ADIZowoI9S8xJms&ithint=folder%2cJPG

Comment: i want to query for specific user the book that they related to jhon smith has 3 book how to get them alone just these 3 books

Comment: You never mentioned you had a field with the user in Table 2.  What you have to do is update the relation field in the Table 2 for each book borrowed to the user and when the book is returned, you have to set it back to NULL

Comment: but i don't know how to query it i just want the data to be displayed i don't want to set anything to null i am trying to find any references how To query all the books borrowed by user 1 or user 2 plz can you help me or give me reference

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.Relation WHERE Table1.ID = [IdUser]`.  [IdUser] is the ID of the user you want to query.  If you only want to see the Book Information you just need to use the query `SELECT Table2.* FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.Relation WHERE Table1.ID = [IdUser]`

Comment: thank you very much you helped alot and i took alot of your time ty mate